# Eclipse не видит файл с приложением

Tags: python, django, eclipse, python-3.7

[image: Здесь я создал заготовок приложения]

Здесь я создал заготовок приложения.

[image: Вот его размещение в дереве папок]

Вот его местоположение в дереве папок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот здесь его должен видеть Eclipse

Что не так?
Подскажите пожалуйста.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Надо просто перевести текст ошибки и станет понятно, что заготовок создавать не нужно.

Comment: Вы про ту, которая вышла после повторного ввода <Python manage.py startapp helloworld?>  В ней же говорится про то, что введённое имя конфликтует с уже существующим, и не может использоваться как стратаповское имя. Нужно новое имя

Comment: А никаких других ошибок не выходило

Comment: Или если я не правильно вас понял, объясните пожалуйста поподробнее

Comment: Вы не можете перевести предложение "'helloworld' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name"? Или вы не понимаете, что предложение "'helloworld' конфликтует с именем существующего модуля Python и не может использоваться в качестве имени приложения" означает "у вас уже есть каталог с таким именем"? Я ведь вам даже подсказку написал, что **заготовок создавать не нужно**.

Comment: Так проблема не в том что я не могу его создать. Проблема в том, что Eclipse его не видит. Он есть в дереве папок(То есть этот каталок можно найти через проводник). Есть подтверждение того, что он был создан(Подчёркнутая команда в командной строке). А Eclipse этот каталог не видит. Из-за этого я пробовал снова вписать эту команду. И только после этого вышла эта ошибка, которая к решению проблемы не имеет отношения.

Comment: Первый раз команда была выполнена!

Comment: Если используете IDE, то не надо запускать команды. Надо кликнуть правой клавишей мыши по проекту, выбрать "PyDev", выбрать "Create application".

Comment: Такая же история. Папки в проводнике появляются, а Eclipse их не видит

Comment: Решил задачу!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Есть такая кнопочка <<Refresh>>!!! Я о ней не знал. Когда увидел ткнул, и всё появилось!!!

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: ...Преогромное!

Comment: Да не за что :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопку ""Refresh"" оказывается нужно было нажать